# Can I register national insurance number without an address nor using a business one?

Tags: united-kingdom, residency, national-id-number

I am an EU national and have an EU-registerd company. I will be coming to the UK to do some long-term contracts. Problem is I will not be staying in one place for long, so I will have no long-term address.

Can I register a national insurance number without having an address? Or can I use one of the services who scan any incoming mail and email it to me or send it to my current AirBnB? Or do I have to register a business?

The primary reason I even need NIN is my health. I have some chronic conditions that I will require a checkup every 3 months, so I would like to have an opportunity to visit some local doctors to update my scripts, etc.

By the way, can I get NHS number without NIN? Or say pay like a monthly subscription to use the services?

Comment: Are you moving to live in the UK? https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number

Comment: @traveller yes I am but nin requires address I don't have one